# registry Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion CurrentVersion = 6.3 instead of 10 for win 10 pro

Tags: windows, registry, version

I'm trying to find a way how to know the CurrentVersion of my windows.

in registry over Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion

we can find a CurrentVersion key

this key has 6.3 for the value

but the key ProductName has Windows 10 Pro as value

the problem is that CurrentVersion should be 10.0 for Windows 10

as mentioned here [Get Windows Version](https://www.arclab.com/en/kb/cppmfc/get-windows-version-from-registry.html)

is Microsoft forgot to update the CurrentVersion when it release win 10 ?

Comment: use `RtlGetNtVersionNumbers` if want get *major.minor.build* versions